# How can a javax.persistence.Column be defined as an Unsigned TINYINT?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, unsigned, tinyint

I am creating a Java Persistence Entity Bean (with NetBeans IDE 8.0.1) based on an existing table in a MySQL database. I've come across a field in this table which is of type *"Unsigned TINYINT(3)"*. I have found that the following can be done to [define the type of a column as an unsigned int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5261992/2541501):

```
private long foo;

@Column(columnDefinition = "UNSIGNED INT(11)")
public long getFoo()
{
    return foo;
}
```

## Steps to reproduce the problem:

I am trying to create a field as follows:

```
@Size(max = 3)
@Column(name = "WorkingHours", columnDefinition="UNSIGNED TINYINT(3) default '40'")
private Integer workingHours;
```

## The problem:

I receive the following error when deploying my project to my server:

```
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"my-project.ear/my-project-ejb.jar#old-db\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"my-project.ear/my-project-ejb.jar#old-db\": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to execute JPA schema generation create command [create table ... etc.]
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to execute JPA schema generation create command [create table ... etc.]
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED TINYINT(3), ... etc.' at line 1"}}
```

If I however remove *"UNSIGNED"* from my `columnDefinition` (so the line becomes `columnDefinition="TINYINT(3) default '40'"`) deployment of my project is successful. So it seems that *"UNSIGNED"* is not recognized.

So my question is: *how do I define my column (field) as an unsigned TINYINT?*

## Some more details:

I'm not sure if it is important, but my *persistence.xml* file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="old-db" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:/jboss/datasources/mySQL_pool_old</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: You can define it as WHATEVER THE RDBMS SUPPORTS, since that statement is simply fed to the RDBMS. So MySQL doesn't allow UNSIGNED presumably

Comment: @NeilStockton but [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) says that a *TINYINT* can be *UNSIGNED*.. (Also see the following SO question: "[mysql Tinyint as unsigned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812362/mysql-tinyint-as-unsigned)")

Comment: Why not just look at the SQL/DDL invoked (by your JPA impl) and try the exact same thing into MySQL console? That tells you whether it does or not.

Comment: @NeilStockton Thanks for the suggestion, it is a good one. However, I just found the answer to my problem. It was not that hard to solve after all. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After experimenting some more I found the answer.

The word *"UNSIGNED"* should come after *"TINYINT"* instead of before it. The field should be defined as follows:

```
@Size(max = 3)
@Column(name = "WorkingHours", columnDefinition="TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED default '40'")
private Integer workingHours;
```

I am not sure why this is, I have found this out only through trial and error. Maybe someone else can provide a reference for why this is.